# Number of elements/words in a shell array variable

Tags: bash, array

I have looked at the question [How to count number of words from String using shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108229/how-to-count-number-of-words-from-string-using-shell) on SO, which explains how to count words inside a variable.

But this only counts one word inside my variable so I have no idea how to fix it.

I have the following variables:

```
vmfarm1=(host1.com host2.com host3.com host4.com )
maximus=(host11.com host 12.com host 13.com)
firefly=(host5.com)
```

I need to find a way to count all the host names into a number inside the variables.

After this, the number inside that was counted, have to be used as a variable in this line.

I have tried:

```
echo "$input" | wc -w
printf ' \n|/4.vmfarm1 ' >>  textfile.txt
```

I have to write the `4` above by myself to the number and I need it to be done automatically, this is why I need a variable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given an array `arr`, its length (number of elements) is given by `${#arr[@]}`.

Using this with your `vmfarm1` array:

```
printf ' \n|/%d.vmfarm1 ' "${#vmfarm1[@]}" >>textfile.txt
```

Answer (score 14):

To print the number of elements in an array variable in various shells with array support:

- `csh`/`tcsh`/`zsh`/`rc`/`es`/`akanga`: `echo $#array`
- `ksh`¹/`bash`¹/`zsh`: `echo "${#array[@]}"`
- `fish`: `count $array`
- `yash`: `echo "${array[#]}"`
- Bourne/POSIX shells (where the only array is `"$@"`): `echo "$#"`

Now for the number of whitespace delimited words in all the elements of an array variable, that's where you may want to use `wc -w`, but you'd need to feed it the content of all the elements separated by at least one white space for instance with:

```
printf '%s\n' $array:q | wc -w        # csh/tcsh
printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" | wc -w   # ksh/bash/zsh/yash
printf '%s\n' $array | wc -w          # fish/zsh/rc/es/akanga
printf '%s\n' "$@" | wc -w            # Bourne/POSIX
```

Or you could do the splitting of the elements into further whitespace-delimited words and count them in the shell itself.

- `csh`/`tcsh` (split on SPC/TAB/NL)

  ```
  (set noglob; set tmp=($array); echo $#tmp)
  ```
- `ksh`/`bash`/`yash` (`$IFS` splitting, SPC/TAB/NL by default)

  ```
  (set -o noglob; set -- ${array[@]}; echo "$#")
  ```
- `zsh` (`$IFS` splitting, SPC/TAB/NL/NUL by default)

  ```
  echo ${#${=array}}
  ```
- `rc`/`es` (`$ifs` splitting):

  ```
  tmp = `{echo $array}
  echo $#tmp
  ```
- `fish` (counts all sequences of non-whitespace (according to PCRE) characters):

  ```
  count (string match -ar -- '\S+' $array)
  ```
- Bourne/POSIX (`$IFS` splitting):

  ```
  (set -f; set -- $@; echo "$#")
  ```

---

<sup>¹ note that given that `ksh`/`bash` arrays are sparse and have indices that start at 0 instead of 1 in every other shell, that number will generally not be the same as the maximum index in the array</sup>

Comment: `wc -w` was what I was looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`vmfarm1, maximus` and `firefly` are not just variables, these are arrays.

Use the proper syntax: `${#vmfarm1[@]}` is the number of entries in your array.

Answer (score 3):

In Bash and ksh, expanding an array as if it was a normal string variable, gives the first element of the array. That is, `$somearray` is the same as `${somearray[0]}`. <sup>(*)</sup>

So,

```
somearray=(foo bar doo)
echo "$somearray"
echo "$somearray" | wc -w
```

prints `foo` and `1`, since `foo` is only one word. If you had `somearray=("foo bar doo" "acdc abba")` instead, then the `wc` would show three words.

You'll need to use `"${somearray[@]}"` to expand all elements of the array as distinct shell words (arguments), or `"${somearray[*]}"` to expand them as a single shell word, joined with spaces <sup>(**)</sup>

In any case, note that the number of elements in an array, and the number of words (in the `wc -w` or the human language sense) are not the same, see below. Use `"${#somearray[@]}"` to get the number of elements in the array.

```
somearray=("foo bar doo" "acdc abba")
echo "${#somearray[@]}"                # 2 elements, that contain
echo "${somearray[@]}" | wc -w         # 5 whitespace separated words in total
```

---

<sub>(*) ignoring sparse and associative arrays for now.</sub>

<sub>(**) assuming default `IFS`</sub>.

Comment: Beware that _first element of an array_ is ambiguous with `ksh` and `bash` as their arrays are space. `$array` expands to `${array[0]}` or the empty string if the array has no element of index 0. For the first element of the array, you actually need `${array[@]:0:1}`.

Answer (score 0):

This may be not smart, but I think you can get number of hosts in array.

```
vmfarm1=(host1.com host2.com host3.com host4.com)
#maximus=(host11.com host12.com host13.com)
#firefly(host5.com)
COUNT=0

for i in ${vmfarm1[@]};
do
    HOSTCOUNT=`echo $i |wc -l`
    COUNT=$((COUNT + HOSTCOUNT))
done

printf "vmfarm1:%2d\n" $COUNT
```

Thanks